# Why won't Excel VBA won't find and replace in Word document

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm fairly new to VBA, trying to fill out a word template from Excel with VBA in Excel. I'm using the following code to put in the Date into a tag in the word document:
 Dim Template As String

```
Dim WordDoc, WordApp As Object
Dim Template as String
On Error Resume Next                                                      
Set WordApp = GetObject("Word.Application")                                 
If Err.Number <> 0 Then                                                     
    Err.Clear                                                               
    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")                          
    WordApp.Visible = True                                                  
End If
Template = "C:\Users\me\Dropbox\me - Summer 2019\RMA_Log\00059-001_E_24May19_Form Returned Authorization.docx"
Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(FileName:=Template, ReadOnly:=False)
With WordDoc.Content.Find                                                   
    .Text = "<Date>"                                                        
    .Replacement.Text = "06-06-2019"                                        
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindContinue                                     
End With
```

But this won't replace any text in the main body of my word document.

I've tried doing `WordDoc.ActiveDocument.Content.Find` but that also doesn't work.  If I copy the code exactly and replace `WordDoc` with `ActiveDocument` and run it in word VBA, the text gets replaced.

```
Dim Template As String
Template = "C:\Users\me\Dropbox\me - Summer 2019\RMA_Log\00059-001_E_24May19_Form Returned Authorization.docx"

With ActiveDocument.Content.Find                                                   
    .Text = "<Date>"                                                        
    .Replacement.Text = "06-06-2019"                                        
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindContinue                                     
End With
```

If I run this code in Word VBA, it replaces the  Tag, why wouldn't it work to run this from Excel?

Edit: Office 2016

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Excel doesn't know what `wdReplaceAll` or `wdFindContinue` are.

Put a reference to the Word Object Model (`Tools > References > Microsoft Word XX Object Model`).

And if you have `Option Explicit` at the top of your code it would highlight this.

Comment: Works exactly how I expect it now, thank you very much!